# Parallax from razorfish.github.io/Parallax-JS/ on non-full-height divs

Tags: jquery, parallax

How can make this script http://razorfish.github.io/Parallax-JS/ work on the background images of the .visual divs on this page: http://bit.ly/1aWpGFr with a position:fixed to achieve a spotify.com-style parallax effect?

Thanks!

The script applies the parallax to all "#content section" tags, and the css makes them 100%-in height. But when I try to use it in my own layout, I can only get it to work if all the divs (including the white divs) are the same height. And I cannot get it to work with a fixed top bar.

My site code looks like this, and I just want the parallax from this script to be applied to the .visual divs and nothing else. I just can't figure out what approach to take - any ideas?

**My code:**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>1986 | Product design studio |</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />





</head>

<body>


<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="visual"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column-left">
        <h1>E-Light&trade;</h1>
        <p class="intro">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="visual" style="background-image:url(images/visual2.jpg)"></div>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="column-right">
        <h1>Methodology</h1>
        <p class="intro">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>

</div>

<!--<div class="footer-space"></div>-->

<div class="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="column">
            <h2>Services</h2>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h2>Keep in touch</h2>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-last">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>
            1986
            Anders Andersen
            Vestergade 12<br />
            5000 Odense<br />
            Denmark
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* end reset */



@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('BebasNeue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body{
    font-family:Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.6em;
    background-color:#fff;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p.intro, .navigation li a {
    font-family:"bebas_neueregular", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1{
    font-size:46px;
    line-height:46px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

h2{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

p{
}

p.intro{
    color:#787878;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}


.header{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:0px 0px -84px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index:50;
}

    .modernizr-fallback-header{
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        margin:0px 0px -84px 0px;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index:50;
    }


.logo{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    display:block;
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    float:left;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-image:url(images/logo.png);
}

.navigation{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    width:600px;
    height:1%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:right;
    margin:24px 0 16px -200px;
}

    .navigation li{
        display:inline;
        height:1%;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin-left:30px;
    }

        .navigation li a, .navigation li a:visited{
            display:inline;
            color:#000;
            font-size:24px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

            .navigation li a:hover{
                color:#777;
                    animation: myanim 0.7s;
               -moz-animation: myanim 0.7s; /* Firefox */
            -webkit-animation: myanim 0.7s; /* Safari and Chrome */
                 -o-animation: myanim 0.7s; /* Opera */
            }

                @-webkit-keyframes myanim {
                  0%   { color:#000; }
                  100% { color:#777; }
                }
                @-moz-keyframes myanim {
                  0%   { color:#000; }
                  100% { color:#777; }
                }
                @-o-keyframes myanim {
                  0%   { color:#000; }
                  100% { color:#777; }
                }
                @keyframes myanim {
                  0%   { color:#000; }
                  100% { color:#777; }
                }

/* OLD WRAPPER          
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    padding:30px 0px 60px 0px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:url(images/whitefade-top.png), url(images/whitefade-bottom.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top, bottom;
    margin-bottom:-160px;


}
*/


.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    padding:30px 0px 45px 0px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:url(images/whitefade-top.png), url(images/white.gif), url(images/whitefade-bottom.png);

    margin-bottom:-160px;

    border-top:160px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:160px solid transparent;

    background-repeat:
        repeat-x,
        repeat,
        repeat-x;
    background-position:
        top,
        center,
        bottom;
    background-origin:
        border-box,
        padding-box,
        border-box;


    -moz-background-clip: border, padding, border;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
  -webkit-background-clip: border, padding, border;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
  background-clip: border-box, padding-box, border-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */

}


.visual-top{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:726px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    z-index:1;
    margin-bottom:-160px;
    background-image:url(images/visual.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    background: url(images/visual.jpg) no-repeat center static; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}

.visual{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:822px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    z-index:1;
    margin-bottom:-160px;
    background-image:url(images/visual.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    background: url(images/visual.jpg) no-repeat center static; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}

.column-left{
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin:-160px 0 -160px -400px;
}

.column-right{
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin:-160px 0 -160px -200px;
}

.column{
    width:180px;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}

.column-last{
    width:180px;
    margin-right:0px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.footer{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#191919;
    height:1%;
    position:hidden;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    z-index:0;
}

    .footer .wrapper{
        background-color:transparent;
        width:800px;
        left:50%;
        margin:160px 0 0 -400px;
        background:none;
        background-color:transparent;
        border:0px;
    }

    .footer p{
        color:#fff;
    }

.footer-space{
    height:200px;
    z-index:-2;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:160px;
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you post the code that is stopping you from getting the desired effect?

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps.